# How to disable AWS SDK logging

Tags: aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm using AWS JavaScript SDK in nodejs application. SDK setup is as below.

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.logger = console;
```

This config is creating too much noise on console and it's difficult to go over the log.
I tried removing `aws.config.logger = console;` but that doesn't change anything, still every log is being printed on console.

Comment: The logger is off by default. You should not be seeing any AWS SDK logs unless you explicitly set `aws.config.logger`. Are you sure that you saw logs after you commented out that assignment?

Comment: @jarmod yes i'm very sure those were from AWS SDK.

Comment: I suspect you were not running the changed code. The AWS JavaScript SDK does not emit logs by default, to the best of my knowledge. So, the accepted answer is not actually necessary at all afaik.

Comment: @jarmod I'm running the updated code, however, this is not the only client I have, there are other aws clients too. but I want to disable the logs specifically for this client as I don't need them. Is it possible that the config defined for other aws client is affecting this one?

Comment: The [config object is global](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/global-config-object.html) for an application, it's not per SDK client. So if you have multiple client objects in the same app, they'll share the global config.

Comment: I stumbled onto this question because I have an error occurring where the SDK is trying to log activity and that is causing it to crash due to a circular reference. (see https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/4339) and I was hoping to disable the logging (that I didn't ask for anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by disable the Main Console to print anything in the log bar.
Put the below code in your main file through which your server get starts.
Here is the code snippet:

```
console.log = function(){};
```

or

```
console = function(){};
```

Your complete code may look like:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
aws.config.logger = console;
console.log = function(){};
```

Comment: Won't this disable ALL console logging throughout the app?